# Failed to load css files

Tags: cakephp

After setting up a fresh copy of CakePHP project, the css reference from the code is:

```
/my_app_name/css/cake.css
```

While the real location of my css files is:

```
/my_app_name/webroot/css/cake.css
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that?

CakePHP, as with most frameworks, makes use of [url rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting) by default (not a requirement, it can also be [turned off](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#i-can-t-use-url-rewriting)). For apache users this is implemented via `.htaccess` files, such as [this one in the root of your application](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And [another in the webroot](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/webroot/.htaccess) - the presence of these files mean url rewriting just-works for the majority of users.

The rules in the application root folder rewrite all requests to the webroot folder, thus these urls are actually equivalent:

```
http://localhost/my_app_name/some/file.css
http://localhost/my_app_name/webroot/some/file.css
```

The primary purpose of these rewrite rules is security - it prevents the possibility of accessing application files outside the webroot folder - something which is not necessary if using [a production install](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production). A side effect of this is that urls remain the same whether it's a development-style or production-style install.

### Use helper classes

Classes such as [the html helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-css-files) take care of knowing where files are and linking to them appropriately, don't be tempted to hardcode the path to your assets in your template files i.e. don't do this:

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my_app_name/css/cake.css" />
```

instead do this:

```
<html>
    <?= $this->Html->css('forms'); ?>
```

Otherwise, you'll find that even something as simple as renaming your application mean links/assets break.

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS files are located in `/app/webroot/css/` (what is default location) you don't have to know nothing else, include them in your template absolute to webroot:

```
<link href="/css/cake.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```